# i need help creating a password form in html/javascript

Tags: javascript, html

i am trying to make a password field and it is not working, if anyone knew what was wrong with
my code (probably everything because this is my second project) i would be very grateful.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">

        <title>Password</title>
        <script>
            (function pw_check() {
  var $password;
  $password = document.write(document.getElementById("password"));
  if ($password = "pass") {window.open("alert.html");} 
  else {window.open("pwfail.html");};
  });

        </script>

        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0">
    </head>

    <body>
        <form>
            <input type="password"/>
            <button onclick="pw_check" id="password">submit</button>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Define "not working".

Comment: you have to put your id = password to your input, not your button.

Answer (score 2):

Two problems:

1. `onclick="pw_check();"`, otherwise you're just referencing the function but not actually calling it
2. Your `pw_check()` function is all kinds of wrong. Try:

   ```
   function pw_check() {
       var pw = document.getElementById('password_input').value;
       if( pw == "pass") location.href = "alert.html";
       else location.href = "pwfail.html";
   }
   ```

   And change your form to this:

   ```
   <form>
       <input type="password" id="password_input" />
       <button type="button" onclick="pw_check();">submit</button>
   </form>
   ```

Answer (score -3):

Add an ID:

You try to get the Element: `document.getElementById("password")` by **ID** and your input **has'nt an ID**:

```
 <input type="password"/>
```

ADD an ID:

```
 <input id="password" type="password"/>
```

and **remove** the ID from the Button - ID's must be unique.

Comment: Button has `id="password"`. You are causing duplicate ID.

Comment: Yes the **button** (sorry not see that) but he want to read the **input** and NOT the **button**.

Comment: This is not going to fix the problem since the function is never even called.

Comment: @AdrianPreuss Okay, but putting the ID on both will only cause more problems.